# Group List of strings based on similarity

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, similarity

I have checked a lot of answers and I can't seem to find a solution to my issue which is surprising because I thought it should be a really common problem.

I have a list of strings that contain similar names and I want to group the list based on similarity.

Example:

```
List<string> items = new List<string> 
{
  "TAB PARACETAMOL 500MG",
  "Panadol extra",
  "Panadol",
  "PANADOL TABS 4X20",
  "Paracetamol"
}
```

For the above example, I want to have 2 groups,

```
1. Panadol
2. Paracetamol
```

The examples I have seen focuses mostly on comparing against a known list or known string, and some examples using `Levenshtein`.

The other examples I have seen are for SQL using SOUNDEX().

I have Levenshtein algorithm implementation, the challenge is how to use it to process the list.

Comment: Do you need to worry about misspellings?

Comment: Offtopic. If you are really about medicines, you should not be based on their names. Use an active substance instead.

Comment: It might be a common problem, but it's also something a human is better at than computers are. I don't see Levenshtein helping you group "Panadol", "Panadol Extra" and "PANADOL  TABS 4x20". Known strings is your best option.

Comment: Lots of problems here. Picking the right word out of every string to apply the grouping is the hard part. E.g. you have five additional entries with different medicine name, but all ending with _extra_? Is then this word also a category? Or lots of entries containing 500mg. Is this a category? So you have to handcraft the categories.

Comment: Try following : var groups = items.GroupBy(x => x.ToUpper().Contains("PARACETAMOL") ? "PARACETAMOL" : "PANADOL")
                .Select(x => x).ToList();

Comment: When dealing with strings you'll also need to take into account language support. Can't you just order them alphabetically ignoring case?

Comment: @rotabor, that's what we are trying to do. We have over 18,000 of drug names most of which are just slightly different. We want to get just one drug name so we can use that to get the active ingredient. Panadol 500mg and Panadol 1000mg both contain same active ingredient in different strengths.

Comment: Sounds good. It mostly resolves your problem because the active ingredient has a single name. You can easily group medicines by their active ingredients. A strength or dosage is another kind not related to ingredient's name.

Comment: All sampled medicines are based on the paracetamol. Panadol is the trademark only.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issuse first is to separate letters from each other and save to directory:

```
            List<string> items = new List<string>
            {
               "TAB PARACETAMOL 500MG",
               "Panadol extra",
               "Panadol",
               "PANADOL TABS 4X20",
               "Paracetamol"
            };

            Dictionary<string, int> frequencyMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            foreach (string item in items)
            {
                string[] words = item.Split(' ');

                foreach (string word in words)
                {
                    string cleanedWord = CleanWord(word);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cleanedWord))
                    {
                        if (frequencyMap.ContainsKey(cleanedWord))
                        {
                            frequencyMap[cleanedWord]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            frequencyMap[cleanedWord] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Clean Word:

```
            private static string CleanWord(string word)
            {
                // Remove any non-alphabetic characters from the word
                string cleanedWord = new 
                   string(word.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());

               // Convert the word to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison
                cleanedWord = cleanedWord.ToLower();

                return cleanedWord;
             }
```

After this directory is available, Repeat the word that is repeated more than once:

```
            List<string> repeatedWords = frequencyMap
                .Where(item => item.Value > 1)
                .Select(item => item.Key)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @ayobkafrashian for this, but it doesn't exactly solve the problem. It splits each string into parts and in some cases, the parts do not have any semantic meaning